# VB.net value 1 showing as a VBNull

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2017

```
dim MyStr as string="1"
If  Convert.toInt32(MyStr)=vbNull Then
System.Console.WriteLine("Null")
Else
System.Console.WriteLine("Not Null")
End If

dim Myval as integer="1"
If  Myval=vbNull Then
   System.Console.WriteLine("Null")
Else
   System.Console.WriteLine("Not Null")
End If
```

This Code returns  'null' even it has a value.
If i put '2' as value it is showing 'not null',
Can anyone explan why this is showing 'null'.

Comment: Your code doesn't really make sense because, as I explained in my answer, that's not how you use `vbNull`. If you explain what you're actually trying to achieve then we can tell you how to achieve it.

Comment: Actually, I want to check if the variable contains a value or is Null, if it is  Null then I have to set a value in that variable

Comment: I suggest that you accept the answer provided here, given that it answers the question you actually asked, and then post a new question asking about what you actually want to do. As I said, no value means `Nothing` but that only applies to reference types and nullable value types. A type like `Integer` always has a value. Also, no `String` and an empty `String` are different things too, so you need to be specific about what you actually need to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a lot wrong there but addressing the specific issue raised, you are confused about what `vbNull` actually is. If you mouse over it in code, you'll see that it is a constant with the value `VariantType.Null`. [`VariantType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.varianttype?view=net-6.0) is an enumeration and, like all enumerations, its fields have numeric values. Guess what the numeric value of the `Null` field is. That's right, it's 1.

In short, you shouldn't be using `vbNull` at all but it's not really possible to say what you should do instead because your question doesn't explain what you're actually trying to achieve. If you want to determine whether a variable has no value then you should be comparing it to `Nothing`. The thing is, for non-nullable value types like `Integer`, `Nothing` will correspond to the default value for that type, e.g. 0.